# 0mq one-to-many connection

Tags: python, multithreading, zeromq

What is the most correct way to establish a two-way communication between processes using 0mq?  I need to create several background processes that will wait for commands from the main process, perform some calculations and return the result back to the main process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. The most straight forward approach might be to use `REQ`/`REP` sockets. Each background process/worker would have a `REP` socket, and you would use a `REQ` socket to communicate with them:

```
import zmq

def worker(addr):
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
    socket.bind(addr)
    while True:
        # get message from boss
        msg = socket.recv()
        # ...do smth
        # send back results
        socket.send(msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # spawn 5 workers
    from multiprocessing import Process
    for i in range(5):
        Process(target=worker, args=('tcp://127.0.0.1:500%d' % i,)).start()
```

You'd have to connect to each worker to send them a message, and get back results:

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect(worker_addr)
socket.send('message')
msg = socket.recv()
```

Another approach would be to use `PUB`/`SUB` to fire off messages to the workers and `PUSH`/`PULL` to harvest results:

```
import zmq

def worker(worker_id, publisher_addr, results_addr):
    context = zmq.Context()
    sub = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    sub.connect(publisher_addr)
    sub.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, worker_id)
    push = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
    push.connect(results_addr)

    while True:
        msg = sub.recv_multipart()[1]
        # do smth, send off results
        push.send_multipart([worker_id, msg])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    publisher_addr = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:5000'
    results_addr = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:5001'

    # launch some workers into space
    from multiprocessing import Process
    for i in range(5):
        Process(target=worker, args=('worker-%d' % i, publisher_addr, results_addr,)).start()
```

To broadcast a command to a specific worker, you'd do something like:

```
context = zmq.Context()
pub = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
pub.bind(publisher_addr)
# send message to worker-1
pub.send_multipart(['worker-1', 'hello'])
```

Pull in results:

```
context = zmq.Context()
pull = context.socket(zmq.PULL)
pull.bind(results_addr)

while True:
    worker_id, result = pull.recv_multipart()
    print worker_id, result
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [Request Reply Broker](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#A-Request-Reply-Broker) but exchange REQ socket into DEALER. DEALER is non blocking for sending and will automatically load balance traffic towards your workers.

In picture `Client` would be your `main process` and `Service A/B/C` are your `background processes (workers)`. `Main process` should bind to an endpoint. `Workers` should connect to main process's endpoint to receive work items.

In `main process` keep list of work items and send time. If there is no answer for some time just resend work item again since `worker` probably died.

[image: Request Reply Broker]